# Keydown Event not firing

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

Trying to fire up an event when a button is pressed on the keyboard. Ive set the Form1 property to have the KeyPreview to True as well. But still, its not firing and i cant see whats wrong.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Modifiers == Keys.A)
    MessageBox.Show("A pressed");
    else if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
    MessageBox.Show("Combination of ALt and F1 pressed");
}
```

Comment: showing the handler wont help, you need to show where you attach the event.

Comment: I hate to see `if` statements without curly braces.

Comment: Why `e.Modifiers`? why not `e.KeyCode`?

Comment: Duplicate: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172731/forms-not-responding-to-keydown-events]
Post more details if problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting the event

```
this.KeyDown += Form5_KeyDown;
this.KeyPreview = true;
```

the event

```
void Form5_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
        MessageBox.Show("A pressed");
    else if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
        MessageBox.Show("Combination of ALt and F1 pressed");
}
```

dont forget the `KeyPreview = true`, if you want to handle all `keydown`

Answer (score 1):

try with KeyCode:

```
if (e.KeyCode==Keys.A)
                MessageBox.Show("A pressed");
            ...
```

Also keep in mind that `Form1` must have the focus when you press the corresponding button

Comment: Tried, still not firing. Also KeyPreview property is set to true on the correct form.

Answer (score 0):

Set the KeyPreview property of the form to true.

Otherwise the child controls will catch the event first.