# Using Keypresses to change picture box

Tags: c#, keypress, keycode, imagelist

I have an imagelist, two buttons and a picturebox. The two buttons are prior and next and they toggle the image in the picture. So far this is working well, however I want to have it so the image changes on a keypress. So far I attempted to use e.Keycode to trigger the button events but this wasn't working. My code is as follows:

**Next Button:**

```
n = n+1;
if (n <= 6)
{
    pbImage.Image = imlImages.Images[n];
    rbDescription.Text = Current[n];
}
else
{
    n = -1;
    pbImage.Image = imlImages.Images[0];
    rbDescription.Text = Current[0];
}
```

**Previous button:**

```
if (n > 0)
{
     n = n - 1;
     pbImage.Image = imlImages.Images[n];
     rbDescription.Text = Current[n];
}
else if (n == 0 || n == -1)
{
     n = 6;
     pbImage.Image = imlImages.Images[6];
     rbDescription.Text = Current[6];
}
```

//n starts at -1

Key presses on Form_Keydown:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
    btnPrior.PerformClick();
else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
    btnNext.PerformClick();
```

Comment: Have you used debugger to verify your key down event is even firing?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `KeyPreview` property to true? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172731/forms-not-responding-to-keydown-events

Comment: I tried putting message boxes where the button press event should launch but they didn't show... Also tried putting the code in the keyup function.

Comment: Thank you, Doom5...The code works!!!