# Can the AcceptButton property on a C# winform be changed from the Enter key to using Ctrl+Enter without using a TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop-application, visual-studio-2019

I'm working on updates to a program I wrote a while ago (and thank you all for helping out with my previous question!), and I've run into a hiccup. I'd like to make it so that my program will submit its data to the SharePoint list using CTRL+ENTER without needing a TextBox.

I've scoured Google Searches for hours and haven't found anything that really gives me the functionality I want. I'm not married to using the AcceptButton feature on the WinForm, so any suggestions to make this work are welcome.

I've tried various variations of this code to make it cooperate, but it didn't work out at all.

```
if (e.SuppressKeyPress = (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.Enter)))
{
SubmitBtn.Focus();
SubmitBtn.PerformClick();
}
```

I just need the program to click a button once CTRL+ENTER is pressed. The button itself does the rest of the work.

Comment: I think the problem comes from the incorrect if condition which should be more like :
if(e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.Enter))

Comment: Can edit your question to add your code for the form?

Comment: @YouneS That didn't work, either, unfortunately.

Comment: @Seabass77 What code would you like to see? There's ~300 lines, some of which contains sensitive data for my company, so it's a bit too much to add it all.

Comment: @BlueJae You have extra code in the if condition. The extra code is (e.SuppressKeyPress = ...)

Comment: @BlueJae Can you tell us which TextBox Property you are using for the code above?

Comment: I'm not using a TextBox property; I'm trying to accomplish this without it. The form does have a multi-line TextBox and a single-line name input TextBox, but it's an optional input. Otherwise, there are 3 combo boxes and some radio buttons with the submit button.

Comment: Can you try looking at this post? Seems to have the same question as you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172731/forms-not-responding-to-keydown-events

Comment: @Seabass77 It does look like what I'm looking for. Basically looks like I can't use the Enter key...Thanks for all the advice! It might not be possible but I still learned a lot from it. :)

Comment: @BlueJae No problem! If you find the solution remember to post it here and accept it so that it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

I actually did manage to get this to work after a lot of trial, error, and splicing together samples from a vast number of different forums. Here's what ended up working for me. If there are any edits that would make it more streamlined, please feel free to let me know.

```
private void SubmitShortcut(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && e.Control)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                SubmitBtn_Click(sender, e);
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Enter && e.Control)
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
        }
```