# keydown event c# not working, to open a panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I want a panel to open in my windows form when the left or right arrow is pressed.

```
 private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
           
                switch (e.KeyCode)
                {
                    case Keys.Control:
                        panel2.Visible = true;
                        panel1.Visible = false;
                        break;
                    case Keys.Right:
                        panel1.Visible = false;
                        panel3.Visible = true;
                        break;
                }
        
        }
```

Comment: Can you please tell us what is going wrong? I see that you have `Keys.Control` in your code. Shouldn't it be `Keys.Left`? Also you are talking about a panel but from you code I can see three.

Comment: oh yeah I had put control to see if that would work. It didn't

Comment: I have 3 panels

Comment: depending on which button is pressed a different panel will be shown

Comment: Do you have the event registered on the form? If not you can do so from the designer by selecting events in the properties tab.

Comment: yes I do, still doesn't work

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172731/forms-not-responding-to-keydown-events). Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Does a breakpoint in that method get hit? What is the value of e.Keycode then?

Comment: I fixed it using    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)