# C#.NET: Display the first 100 elements of a char array in a label, then move one element at a time to a read-only text box as they are typed?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, winforms, inputstream

I'm doing my first project for a co-op in C#.NET as a windows form. It's a typing game that will load in a .txt file. Then the contents of the .txt file are to be displayed in a label. The catch is, only the first 100 characters can be displayed. Then the user must 'type along' with what is displayed. For each correct character they type, that character is then removed from the label and moved to read-only textbox. Then the original label is updated so that an additional character is loaded in at the end (since we now only have 99 characters in the label - we always want 100). If you type the wrong character, nothing happens.

I simply cannot figure out how to go about this other than the steps I have so far - creating a char array from the .txt file. Here is my code (the sub I am stuck on is the lowest one):

```
        string FileContent = string.Empty;
        string FilePath = string.Empty;

        //File Browser and Uploader
        private void btnOpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                //Filters the file types so we can only choose .txt files.
                openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
                openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
                openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    //Get the path of specified file.
                    FilePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

                    //Read the contents of the file into a stream.

                    var fileStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile();

                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                    {
                        FileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

            //Loader for the Input Stream
            InputStreamLoader();

        }

        //Applies File Text to Input Stream
        private void InputStreamLoader()
        {
            char[] characters = FileContent.ToCharArray();                            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172731/forms-not-responding-to-keydown-events), you have to register your keys pressed as an event that get's triggered. The method that is then called simply has to check against the first char inside your array.

So store your array on the form or as static variable to access it inside your event method, then simply compare the first charArray element with the input received (I guess the available Properties "Keys.O" contain some strings as output, if not you have to make a switch to handle each key. After that simply compare it.

`if(e.KeyCode.ToLower() == charArray[0]) { // do stuff }`

If the condition is true, then either set the first item to a specific character you could skip/ignore on next runs, or copy the array to a new one, except the first item.

The textBox.Text will always show the first 100 chars of your array (or skipp x items depending on the replaced special char you might use).

I hope this helps you figure out the way to go.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will definitely give this a try.