# KeyPress F1 does not work C#

Tags: c#, keypress

I'm designing a device app. Compact Framework 2.0

I want the user to press F1 to navigate to the next screen, but it does not work.

Can't seem to find a solution.

Is it possible?

This is how I normally use Keypress:

This works:

```
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.M)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("M pressed");
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

This dos NOT work:

```
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.F1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("F1 pressed");
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Comment: "Duplicate"  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951496/how-do-i-capture-keys-f1-regardless-of-the-focused-control-on-a-form

Comment: Do you want to achieve this in C# or javascript?

Comment: Do u have a function key (fn) on your device? In other words do u have to press fn+F1 to access F1's functionality?

Comment: @Paddyd you don't need to press the function key

Comment: @RameshRams I have tried that example. And it does not work for me.

Comment: @WernervandenHeever . Try to below answers !!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.KeyPreview = true;
    this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
}

void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "F1")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("F1 pressed");
    }
}
```

Comment: While this does actually work, I really think you should consider ANY of the other answers - Use the Enum values, instead of comparing strings.

Comment: So it should read: `if (e.KeyData == Keys.F1)`

Answer (score 7):

Refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951496/how-do-i-capture-keys-f1-regardless-of-the-focused-control-on-a-form)

You can override the `ProcessCmdKey` method of your form class and use `keyData == Keys.F1` to check whether F1 is pressed. Above link has example as follows.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.F1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed the F1 key");
        return true;    // indicate that you handled this keystroke
    }

    // Call the base class
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some keys(like f1,f2,arrow keys ,tab ....)cannot be "captured" by keychar for that you need to use keycode:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

keychar property - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use `KeyDown` instead of `KeyPress`:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.F1)
    {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Also set [`KeyPreview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) to `true`