# Set Focus to a text box when F1 is pressed

Tags: vb.net

I have been trying to get this to work but it's doing my head in, wondered if you experts can help me out.

On my form I would like to set focus to a `TextBox` when I press F1 on the keyboard, I have the code written but somehow it does not work when I press F1. What am I doing wrong? I have also set keypreview to true.

The code here:

```
 Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
        If e.KeyData = Keys.F1 Then
            txtemployeeno.Focus() 
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `KeyUp` event isn't firing because the form doesn't technically have input focus (though it may be activated).  If you wish to use the `KeyPreview` property, you need to use the `KeyPress` event instead of `KeyUp`.

Alternatively, you could always override the `ProcessCmdKey` function.  Just add the following method to your form's code:

```
   Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
      If keyData = Keys.F1 Then
         txtemployeeno.Focus()
         Return True
      End If

   Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
   End Function
```

Comment: I've changed it, but i get keydata is not a member of system.windowsforms.keypresseventsargs?

Comment: You won't be able to check the key data very easily using KeyPress.  My suggestion above to use `ProcessCmdKey` might be a better fit for what you're doing.  Additional Reading: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17948204/590783

Comment: I hate to play this card but it works on my machine. =(  You placed the `ProcessCmdKey` code in the form that contains your text box right?  Please place a breakpoint on `txtemployeeno.Focus()` and ensure that you are reaching that line of code.