# if (e.KeyChar == (char)ConsoleKey.F1); Empty Statement? C# Visual Studio .NET Form

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

So I finally figured out how to bind the button I wanted to bind on my soundboard but now the code gives me an error.

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line
Warning CS0642 Possible mistaken empty statement WindowsFormsApplication6 C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication6\Form1.cs 125
```

I feel like I'm missing something but I really cant see what I have missed.
I tried a few different solutions but it didnt do me any good, I tried some trial and error and that just made me end up back here.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    /// <summary>
    /// Version: 1.0
    /// Farm SoundBoard
    /// Created By Me
    /// Date 2015-10-29
    /// Category: Fun
    /// </summary>
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
                player.Stream = Properties.Resources.cow;
                player.Play();
            }

            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
                player.Stream = Properties.Resources.bird;
                player.Play();
            }

            private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
                player.Stream = Properties.Resources.bee;
                player.Play();
            }

            private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
                player.Stream = Properties.Resources.elephant;
                player.Play();
            }

            private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
                player.Stream = Properties.Resources.tiger;
                player.Play();
            }

            private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
                player.Stream = Properties.Resources.cat;
                player.Play();
            }

            private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
                player.Stream = Properties.Resources.dog;
                player.Play();
            }

            private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
                player.Stream = Properties.Resources.lion;
                player.Play();
            }

            private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
                player.Stream = Properties.Resources.flies;
                player.Play();
            }

            private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
                player.Stream = Properties.Resources.fish;
                player.Play();
            }

            private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
                player.Stream = Properties.Resources.parrot;
                player.Play();
            }

            private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
                player.Stream = Properties.Resources.car;
                player.Play();
            }
            private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                panel1.Visible = true;
            }

            private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                panel1.Visible = false;
            }

        private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)ConsoleKey.F1) ;

            System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
            player.Stream = Properties.Resources.cow;
            player.Play();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: `if (e.KeyChar == (char)ConsoleKey.F1) ;` See the semi-colon at the end? That means that the `if` statement ends there. Its saying that you aren't doing anything with the `if`. If its supposed to run the 3 lines under it, you need to wrap them in brackets just like you do with methods.

Comment: That worked! I cant belive I didnt see that! One small issue left, it doesnt respond to the keybind. (F1)

Comment: Try setting the form property KeyPreview to true, otherwise whatever control is active will get the key press first and probably swallow it before it gets to the form level.

Comment: That didnt do the trick, I will take haneys advice & google it & if I get stuck open another question about this subject, thanks for the help!

Comment: Another trick: Use the `KeyUp` event instead, it has a `KeyCode` property that directly maps to keys like you want. For example, in the `KeyUp` event, your if statement would look like this: `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)`, see this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup(v=vs.110).aspx I think the problem you have is that you are trying to convert a ConsoleKey to a char, and F1 is not a printable character (and doesn't have a char code).

Comment: Thanks! I will try that out!

Comment: I think I will have to use that because when I tried to simulate a mouse press it didnt work either

            if (e.KeyChar == (char)ConsoleKey.F1)

               {

                button1_Click(null, null);

Comment: Sorry for inundating you, but here is another solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948204/keypress-f1-does-not-work-c-sharp `if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "F1")` and still use the KeyPress event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)ConsoleKey.F1) ;
```

An `if` statement encapsulates some code to execute only *if* the condition is `true`. If statements in C# typically encapsulate their body of conditional code in `{ }` brackets. As a courtesy, the compiler assumes that a lack of brackets means that there's one line in the conditional body: the next line of code you write. In your case, you've basically written:

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)ConsoleKey.F1) { }
```

Because the `;` at the end of the if statement terminates the line of code. What you might do is this:

```
 if (e.KeyChar == (char)ConsoleKey.F1) /* some code here */;
```

Or this:

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)ConsoleKey.F1)
{
    // Some code here
}
```

Comment: That worked! So that issue is solved! Now I just need to get the F1 to respond and actually do something, because for the time being it doesnt play the sound when the keybind (F1)  is being pressed.

Comment: @HaleyAlisson experiment, Google (and hopefully find the answer on our site!). If you get stuck with that, ask a second question on that topic. :)

Answer (score 0):

So this is what happend.

I tried to allow the KeyPreview & KeyDown in the form properties & it didnt work but as soon as I tried adding the same function with code it worked.

Here is what worked

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.KeyPreview = true;
    this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(button1_KeyDown);
}
```

And

```
private void button1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "F1")

    {
        button2_Click(null, null);
    }
```

So I still had to simulate the button being pressed by the mouse but hey it worked!