# Detect pressed key on form

Tags: c#

I want to detect pressed key on my form. Let's say I want to show message when `F1` key is pressed.

I added code to `KeyUp` event related with `Form1`

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Key Pressed ");
    }
}
```

The thing is, that pressing F1 does not do anything. Not at all. Does anybody have any idea why does that not work?

## Solution

I had to change Form1 `KeyPreview` properties to "true" and delete `this.Controls.Add(this.webControl1);` from `InitializeComponent()` in `Form1.Designer.cs`

Does anybody know how to solve my problem without deleting row from `InitializeComponent()`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to handle the key press event irrespective of the control that currently has the focus then you should consider override the [`Control.ProcessCmdKey()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey(v=VS.100).aspx) method.

Here is a example: [How do I capture Keys.F1 regardless of the focused control on a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951496/how-do-i-capture-keys-f1-regardless-of-the-focused-control-on-a-form)

Comment: It started to work when I set `KeyPreview` to true and deleted 1 row. You have Solution in my first post. Can you look at it? Im wondering why i had to delete `WebControl`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `form` has the KeyPreview property set to true.

> **Form.KeyPreview Property**
>
> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the form will receive key
>   events before the event is passed to the control that has focus.

[image]

Comment: I changed KeyPreview to `true` (it was set to `false` before), but still that does not solve my problem. It still doesn't do anything. What has to be said, when I created new project and did what you said it worked. Messagebox was showing as a charm Every single Form1 properties on my application and on new one was the same.

In both projects `Form1()` looks the same. There is only `InitializeComponent();` there, But why in first case it not working, but in brand new project it works?

Comment: @audiophonic Because of input focus. By default, messages like "key pressed" are only sent to the control that has focus. If you have a clean project, with only the form, the message goes to the form, since it has focus. When you add a control, it will have focus and will get the message instead of the form.

Comment: So why does that not work with `KeyPreview` set on true? It should ignore currently focused control.

Answer (score 1):

You surely don't have a blank form but a form that contains some controls like textboxes etc...

If you press a key, this event is raised for the control that currently has the focus. So the for example the `KeyUp` event for your `TextBox` is raised, but not for your form.

To ensure the event is raised in your `Form` before it is raised for the focused control, set the `KeyPreview` property of your `Form` to `true`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
        this.KeyPreview = true;
    }
    ...
```

Or as [Sadiq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38479795/5528593) showed, set it in the UI designer.

Comment: It started to work when I set `KeyPreview` to true and deleted 1 row. You have Solution in my first post. Can you look at it? Im wondering why i had to delete `WebControl`