# KeyDown event not being called

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // The program flow does not enter this scope.

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Ummm, if debugging does the event get called.  If so, inspect e

Comment: Uwe Keim, it's not certain that the comment meant the `if` scope and not the method scope. Your edit *may* be changing the nature of the question, so I reverted it until the OP provides more context.

Comment: See [Disadvantage of setting Form.KeyPreview = true?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2386980/719186)

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Agreed!

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `KeyPreview` property of the Form to `true`

As per MSDN

> When this property is set to true, the form will receive all KeyPress,
>   KeyDown, and KeyUp events. After the form's event handlers have
>   completed processing the keystroke, the keystroke is then assigned to
>   the control with focus. For example, if the KeyPreview property is set
>   to true and the currently selected control is a TextBox, after the
>   keystroke is handled by the event handlers of the form the TextBox
>   control will receive the key that was pressed. To handle keyboard
>   events only at the form level and not allow controls to receive
>   keyboard events, set the KeyPressEventArgs.Handled property in your
>   form's KeyPress event handler to true.

This can be done either at design time, by simply setting true for Form's `KeyPreview`

or to manually do it

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        base.KeyPreview = true;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: still not working , the same problem unfortunately !

Comment: @user3763059 - i would suggest you to follow this answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386695/disadvantage-of-setting-form-keypreview-true/2386980#2386980

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ProcessCmdKey` override:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Right)
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Right key pressed");

    return true;
}
```

Comment: i had set it , and the same problem !

Comment: @user3763059 Make sure the KeyDown event is wired up:  `this.KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;` or simply use the override: `protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e) {}`.

Comment: it's done - in the form design code 
this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyDown);

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
KeyboardState ks = new KeyboardState();
if(ks.isKeyDown(Keys.Right)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Right key pressed");
}
```

Note: This is off the top of my head so may not be 100% accurate but I'm 98% sure that it will work :)